# How can I chain functions that take the previous result and that fulfill a strict order?

Tags: rust

Example:

```rust
let response = add_customer(InputCustomer)
    .validate()?
    .generate_code()
    .create(DB::create(pool_conextion))?;
```

I tried using various structures, but I don't know if it is the best way to do it:

```rust
struct InputCustomer {}

fn add_customer(i: InputCustomer) -> Validate {
    Validate {
        result: InputCustomer {},
    }
}

struct Validate {
    result: InputCustomer,
}

impl Validate {
    fn do_validate() -> GenCode {
        // valdiate struct customer
        GenCode {
            result: InputCustomer {},
        }
    }
}

struct GenCode {
    result: InputCustomer,
}

impl GenCode {
    fn generate_code() -> Create {
        // generate customer code
        Create { result: true }
    }
}

struct Create {
    result: bool,
}
```

Comment: If they need to be in that order every time, can't you wrap them in one big public function?

Comment: The idea is only to know the result, not the process, example receive the result of registering in the DB

Comment: @lolad Also state machines are much more ergonomic than one big public function, and you can send data back to the client after each function and propagate errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement all the functions on a single struct using [phantom type parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/phantom.html). The `Customer` struct holds some `state`:

```rust
pub struct Customer<State> {
    state: PhantomData<State>,
}
```

We can create the possible states that a `Customer` can be in:

```rust
pub struct CustomerStateNew;
pub struct CustomerStateValidated;
pub struct CustomerStateWithCode;
```

When you create a `Customer`, it's state is `CustomerStateNew`:

```rust
pub fn add_customer() -> Customer<CustomerStateNew> {
    Customer { state: PhantomData }
}
```

To validate a `Customer` it must be in the `CustomerStateNew` state:

```rust
impl Customer<CustomerStateNew> {
    pub fn validate(&self) -> Customer<CustomerStateValidated> {
        Customer { state: PhantomData }
    }
}
```

The `Customer` must be validated (`CustomerStateValidated`) to generate a code:

```rust
impl Customer<CustomerStateValidated> {
    pub fn generate_code(&self) -> Customer<CustomerStateWithCode> {
        Customer { state: PhantomData }
    }
}
```

And it must have a generated code (`CustomerStateWithCode`) to be created. `create` consumes `self`, so the customer cannot be used after it is created (you might not want this behavior, but I included it here for completeness):

```rust
impl Customer<CustomerStateWithCode> {
    pub fn create(self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now we can chain together the methods to create the user:

```
let result = add_customer().validate().generate_code().create()?;
```

However, it we try to create the `Customer` before it is validated, the code will not compile:

```rust
let result = add_customer().create();

// error[E0599]: no method named `create` found for struct `Customer<CustomerStateNew>`
//   --> src/main.rs:36:20
// 36 |     add_customer().create();
//   |                    ^^^^^^ method not found in `Customer<CustomerStateNew>`
```

Also, no one else can create a `Customer` with an arbitrary state, because the `state` field is private:

```rust
mod somewhere_else {
    fn bla() {
        let customer: Customer<CustomerStateWithCode> = Customer { state: PhantomData };
        customer.create();
    }
}

// error[E0451]: field `state` of struct `Customer` is private
//    --> src/main.rs:41:64
//    |
// 41 |  let customer: Customer<CustomerStateWithCode> = Customer { state: PhantomData };
//    |
```

If you want to store data specific to each state, you can store that actual `State` inside the `Customer` instead of `PhantomData`. Now however, the `state` is more than just compile time safety and will be stored at runtime:

```rust
pub struct CustomerStateWithCode(pub usize);

pub struct Customer<State> {
    state: State,
}

impl Customer<CustomerStateValidated> {
    pub fn generate_code(&self) -> Customer<CustomerStateWithCode> {
        Customer { state: CustomerStateWithCode(1234) }
    }
}
```

We have created a simple state machine using phantom types. This is also knows as the *type state pattern*. Note that the states will be compiled away to nothing, so there is no runtime cost, only compile time safety!

[*Playground link*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58fca0be5d2cdfc1986d1f20031bc4d7)

Comment: What's the reason to use `PhantomData<State>` instead of just `State`? All the state types are zero-sized in the first example anyway, so there shouldn't be much difference.

Comment: On advantage I see is that you don't need to implement derive `Debug` and `Clone` for you state types if you want these traits for `Customer`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well if `state` is purely for compile time safety then `PhantomData<State>` is clearer in my opinion. It also simplifies other things as you mentioned, but you could do it either way

Comment: @SvenMarnach but at runtime it is the same

Comment: @BeGo No problem, glad to have helped! If you mark this as the correct answer, it will let future visitors know that this correctly answers the question.